# Какие ещё принципиально разные способы реализации функций min и max вам известны?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, битовые-операции

Для подготовки видеолекции по функциям min и max, я бы хотел узнать у сообщества о принципиально разных способах реализации этих функций, о которых мне неизвестно. Принципиально разные - это которые отличаются по своему логическому смыслу, а не по реализации. Я напишу то, что известно мне, а в ответах прошу написать то, что я мог упустить. Давайте рассматривать только знаковые числа, с беззнаковыми общий принцип тот же, но формулы чуть другие.

**Первое**: обычное сравнение:

```
max = a>b?a:b;
min = a<b?a:b;
```

**Второе**: сначала определяем функцию doz(a,b), которая равна a-b, если a>=b, и нулю в противном случае. Эта функция может быть реализована многими способами:

```
doz = a>=b?a-b:0;
```

или

```
doz = (a-b)&-(a>=b)
```

или

```
d = a-b;
doz = (d&(~(d^((a^b)&(d^a))) >> 31));
```

Далее просто пишем:

```
max = b + doz(a,b);
min = a - doz(a,b);
```

или, объединяя идеи:

```
max = ((a^b)&-(a>=b))^b;
min = ((a^b)&-(a<=b))^b;
```

**Третье**: если мы точно знаем, что при промежуточных вычислениях не будет переполнения или заёма, то считаем doz так:

```
doz = (a-b)&~((a-b)>>31);
```

при этом min и max считаем через doz как было выше.

**Четвертое**: тоже предполагаем, что разность и сумма не переполняют переменные:

```
max = (a+b)/2 + abs(a-b)/2;
min = (a+b)/2 - abs(a-b)/2;
```

При этом функцию abs мы реализуем самыми разными способами (несколько вариантов можно почерпнуть [здесь](http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/017/)), от этого идея не меняется.

Это всё, что мне известно (надеюсь я не допустил опечаток). Есть ли другие способы, которые отличаются от этих принципиально, то есть не перестановкой операций или заменой одних действий на аналогичные (иначе можно ещё дюжину формул наклепать), а именно самой идеей? Вот этим я и прошу поделиться.

Comment: Возьмите книгу Уоррена "Алгоритмические трюки для программистов" - там таких вещей множество...

Comment: К сожалению, там есть только способы 2 и 3 из моего списка (по крайней мере, в моём издании), в двух вариантах: со знаком и без знака.

Comment: Способы с битовыми трюками подходят только для целочисленных типов (и наверняка опираются на арифметику в дополнительном коде, которая вовсе не обязана быть на всех платформах). [Ещё у вас используется константа 31, которую тоже нужно по хорошему задавать переносимым образом.] [А ещё ваш код возможно ориентирован лишь на Little Endian-платформы.] Вам стоит ещё рассмотреть числа с плавающей запятой, а также другие объекты, на которых определена операция сравнения.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку. Да, вместо 31 может быть и 63, и 15, и 7 - зависит от размера целого типа. Действительно, меня интересуют только целые типы. От порядка байт данный код не зависит, а действительно может зависеть от представления отрицательных чисел (дополнительный код). Давайте считать, что у нас архитектура x86, как наиболее распространённая в бытовой сфере.

Comment: @АртёмКараваев: Вроде бы всё же от порядка байт зависит. Например, сдвиг вправо на 31 бит предполагает, что знаковый бит находится в самом левом, а не в самом правом байте. (Если я не ошибаюсь.)

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы путаете абстракцию и способ хранения данных. Тип int - это абстракция, которая состоит из 32-х бит и у неё чётко прописаны правила работы, а способ хранения (как именно биты и байты лежат в памяти) - это уже реальное расположение операнда в памяти. Этим занимается компилятор: скрывает от пользователя вопрос того, как что и где хранится, предоставляя чётко определённый стандартом языка тип данных. Более того, при желании все 32 бита могут вообще находиться в разных частях памяти, задача компилятора это учесть и выполнить сдвиг правильно.

Comment: Я решил систематизировать свои представления по вопросу и написал две статьи. 1. [Функции min(a,b) и max(a,b) для чисел со знаком](http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/019/)
2. [Функции min(a,b) и max(a,b) для чисел без знака](http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/020/) К статьям прилагаются видео. Помимо основной теории предлагаются результаты экспериментов.

Comment: @VladD знаковый сдвиг вправо отрицательного числа - это вообще UB. И уже есть компиляторы, которые это учитывают.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, а это не важно. Слово UB придумали те, кто занимается обычным профессиональным программированием, чтобы не создавать трудностей друг другу. Есть и другие разделы науки, где люди умеют (и вынуждены) работать правильно в том числе с грязными трюками. Иными словами, UB - это не приговор.

Comment: @Zealint вы заблуждаетесь. UB надо избегать даже при выполнении грязных трюков.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, нет, не заблуждаюсь. "Надо" - это догма. Если нужно, то можно.

Comment: @Zealint: Ну это лишь в случае, если документация на компилятор гарантирует поведение. Если нет, ждите сюрпризов :-(

Comment: @VladD, как правило, чрезвычайно сложная вычислительная задача, ради которой всё это затевается, решается под конкретную машину и на одном конкретном языке, когда так называемое UB имеет ВСЕГДА гарантированное поведение.

Comment: @Zealint: Ну это если вам повезёт с компилятором. А вот из-за UB приходится компилировать ядро линукса не с `-O3`, а с `-O2`. Потеря скорости получилась как раз как следствие применения сомнительных техник для выигрыша в скорости.

Comment: @VladD, потому что ядро надо было писать без UB, это же очевидно. При грамотном подходе узкие места пишутся на ассемблере, и там описанные мною трюки реализуются без всякого UB, если речь идёт о конкретной машине. Я вот не понимаю, что так все на меня накинулись сегодня :) Мы с Вами говорим о _разных_ вещах!

Answer (score 3):

Все способы кроме первого - крайне неудачные идеи.

Дело в том, что функции `min` и `max` определены на любых [*линейно упорядоченных множествах*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) - и могут применяться на них. Иными словами, для того, чтобы функции `min` и `max` имели смысл - достаточно одного оператора сравнения.

Все альтернативные способы используют дополнительные операторы - а потому не могут применяться на тех множествах, где эти операции не определены.

Такие задачи возникают чаще, чем вам кажется:

1. Строки. На строках определен лексикографический порядок - но строки нельзя складывать и вычитать. Даже если определить сложение как конкатенацию - у нее не те свойства по отношению к лексикографическому порядку.
2. Вещественные числа. Реализация min/max на основе сравнения не теряет точность. Реализации через сложение и вычитание ведут к потере точности. Битовые операции не определены.
3. Структуры. Для структур можно определить операции "minBy/maxBy" - нахождение минимума или максимум по некоторому полю. В то же время, складывать или вычитать структуры целиком может не получиться (например, если в другом поле - строка или массив).

Comment: С вещественными числами я бы поспорил. Дело в том, что, по крайней мере, в IEEE-754, их сравнение выполняется через интерпретацию чисел как целых. Если числа одного знака - целочисленные представления этих чисел упорядочены так же, как их вещественные значения.

Comment: @Zealint да, но при этом язык не дает доступа к целочисленным представлениям вещественных чисел

Comment: это уже другой вопрос. Мой вопрос состоял в том, какие бывают способы, вы же рассуждаете о том, что язык что-то не даёт делать. На самом деле есть языки, которые дают это сделать. Например, assembler, c++ и c.

Comment: @Zealint нет, я рассуждаю о том, что вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Данным алгоритмическим трюкам уделено довольно много времени разных исследователей. По ним пишутся статьи и книги. Сравнения показывают, что в ряде случаев можно выиграть по скорости, используя те или иные приёмы. И потом, если вопрос не имеет смысла, зачем было отвечать? Вы заблуждаетесь. Если Вам не знакома отрасль программирования, где всё это с успехом применяется, то вряд ли имеет смысл так категорично бросаться догмами из обычной профессиональной сферы программирования. Но я не стану Вас переубеждать, кому надо, тот разберётся сам.

Comment: @Zealint только не удивляйтесь когда в вашей программе обнаружится "загадочный" баг

Comment: Давайте так поступим. Я понимаю, что я для вас - никто. Это хорошо, и мне это даже нравится. Но вот попробуйте написать Генри Уоррену мл., что большая часть его книги про алгоритмические трюки - туфта, не имеющая смысла. Второй момент: баг не обнаружится по той простой причине, что при решении чрезвычайно трудных вычислительных задачах (под которые всё и затевается) реализация затачивается под конкретную машину и конкретный компилятор, когда ваше UB, которого все так боятся, имеет полностью предсказуемое поведение. Поэтому я предлагаю завершить заведомо проигрышный для вас спор